# Running SBT from a sub-project directory

Tags: scala, sbt, multi-project, subproject

I have a `cd` alias for `project` so it's possible to start `sbt` then `cd` into a sub-project and do whatever.  Is it possible to complement this somehow so that if `sbt` is started from some `foo` sub-project directory then it's as if I ran `cd ..; sbt "project foo" "$@"`? (I could hack some shell script wrapper, but it's a project with many people so that won't help.)

If not, then is it possible to make it spit out an error when started in a sub-project instead of pretending that that's a project and messing stuff up?